# Kendo Grid UI transport.destroy is not firing the service in datasource

Tags: kendo-grid, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Kendo UI, While I am using the Kendo Grid UI which is consuming the service, the read operation is working fine and the Grid is populated with the data from services but the delete operation is not working

I have tested the delete service using the fiddler getting a perfect response,but I confused why the delete button in kendo grid is not firing the endpoint

I struggled for past one week but no improvement

This is my code,

```
      var carsDataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource(
      {

          batch: true,
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url: "/DesktopModules/MyServicesTest/API/DropData/Drop",
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "GET",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              },
              destroy: {

                  url: function(options)
              {
                   return 'DesktopModules/MyServicesTest/API/DeleteCategory/
                    Delete' + options.models[0].id;

                  },
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "DELETE"
              }, 
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                  if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                      var CategoryID = options.models[0].id;
                      console.log(CategoryID);
                      return CategoryID;
                  }
              }
          },
            shema:
  {
      model: {
          id: "CategoryID",
          field: {
              CategoryID:
                 {
                     editable: false,
                     nullable: true,
                     type: "number"
                 },
             CategoryName:
                  {
                      editable: false,
                      nullable: false,
                      type: "string"
                  },

          }
      }
  }
      });


    $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: carsDataSource1,
        height: "500px",
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },

        columns: [
              {
                  field: "CategoryID",
                  title: "number "
              },
            {
                field: "CategoryName",
                title: "Name"

            },

        { command:"destroy"}
        ],
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: "inline",
        destroy:true,

    });



});
```

Comment: I'd start with fixing up your code - I'm assuming one of your lines should be `return 'DesktopModules/[path]/Delete' + options.models[0].id;` but it's hard to tell with mismatched quotes and strange indentation.

Comment: Yes that is return of my service endpoint then am concatenating the id of the particular row with the URL to delete the record in table based on catergoryid

Comment: You can edit your code in your question - it would make it easier for people to help you if you applied consistent formatting/indentation, making sure all your brackets, etc., line up.

Comment: yes sure Amos, Just tell me what are the kendo script I need to include to enable the edit, delete functionality in grid, because while clicking delete button in Kendo grid it's not firing my service.

Comment: You have a typo: `shema` should be `schema`